# Microsoft Solver Foundation NelderMeadSolver settings

Tags: c#

I've implemented an optimizer in C# using the NelderMeadSolver provided by Microsoft Solver Foundation 3.1.

Yet compared to the Matlab function fminsearch , which also uses the nelder-mead algorithm as it claims in the help document, the optimizer I implemented always gives inferior result if I keep the number of iteration the same. In other words, to get a similar optimization result, the optimizer I implement takes much more iterations.

Personally I think this may be due to some internal settings of the solver, such as the step size etc. However, I do not know how to change those settings in c#. Does anyone know how to do that?